# MySQL: Why does basic MySQLdump on db table fail with "Permission denied"

Tags: mysql

This should be quick and simple, but after researching on Google quite a bit I am still stumped.  I am mostly newbie with: server admin, CLI, MySQL.

I am developing my PHP site locally, and now need to move some new MySQL tables from my local dev setup to the remote testing site.  First step for me is just to dump the tables, one at a time.

I successfully login to my local MySQL like so:

```
Govind% /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot
```

but while in this dir (and NOT logged into MySQL):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

...when I try this

```
mysqldump -uroot -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql
```

..then I keep getting this:

```
"myTestDumpedTable.sql: Permission denied."
```

Same result if I do any variation on that (try to dump the whole db, drop the '-p', etc.)

I am embarrassed as I am sure this is going to be incredibly simple, or just reveal a gaping  (basic) hole in my knowledge. .. but please help ;-)

Comment: mu, thanks for the reminder about formatting ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer came from a helpful person on the MySQL list:
As you guys (Anson and krazybean) were thinking - I did not have permission to be writing to the `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` dir.  But starting from any other directory, calls to `mysqldump` were failing because my shell PATH var (if I said that right) is not yet set up to handle `mysqldump` from another dir.  Also, for some reason I do not really understand yet, I also needed to use a full path on the **output**, even if I was calling mysqldump effectively, and even if I had permission to write to the output dir (e.g. `~/myTestDumpedTable.sql`.  So here was my ticket, for now (quick answer):

```
Govind% /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p myDBname myTableName > /Users/Govind/myTestDumpedTable.sql
```

You can write to wherever your shell user has permission to do so.  I just chose my user's home dir.

Hope this helps someone someday.
Cheers.

Comment: Glad you were able to get your question answered. FYI, you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer. You won't get rep for that of course, but you'll help others who come across this page in the future.

Comment: Nope! did not work.  (Errcode: 13)' when trying to dump tablespaces

Comment: In my case I needed to use sudo in order for mysqldump to redirect the output to a file without a Permission Denied error.  So my command looked something like this: sudo bash -c "<<path to mysqldump>>" -d -h hostname -u user -ppassword schema > <<path to output file>>".  The key point to note here is to pay attention to the Permission Denied error and note whether it originates from bash or mysql.  The former deals with sudo and directory permissions, while the latter deals with mysql permissions.

Comment: In addition, you can also avoid using the redirect in favor of using the --result-file=foo.sql option of mysqldump.  It makes some of this stuff a bit easier.

Comment: My problem was that I was writing to a directory I didn't own, and for some reason, sudo wasn't making that work. So once I wrote the .sql file to a different directory, it worked.

Comment: using fully qualified paths for the mysqldump command and where to write files worked for me. Thanks for this!

Comment: I needed my backup DBs to be individually dated somehow, and to run from a launch agent. However, introducing a variable into the destination path e.g. `"/Users/myusername/Desktop/SQL_backups/$timestamp.sql"` reintroduced the permissions issue noted above. Solution: `mkdir "/Users/myusername/Desktop/SQL_backups/$timestamp"` `cd "/Users/myusername/Desktop/SQL_backups/$timestamp"` and then use a simple filename for the backup file. Now the subdirectories have timestamps, which is great.

Answer (score 3):

Generally I stick with defining the hostname anyways, but as you being root doesn't seem like it would be the problem, I would question where are you writing this to? What happens when you dump to > ~/myTestDumpedTable.sql

Comment: krazybean,
well I must be getting in even deeper over my head.. because it boggles my mind the response I get when I try this:  
    Govind% mysqldump -uroot -p myDBname myTableName > ~/myTestDumpedTable.sql

..then I get this:  
    "mysqldump: Command not found."

As if the location of the result file changes what commands are known?!

Comment: it turns out (see @Anson's answer and my comments to him) that trying to write the dump file to my user's home dir does produce a properly-named file there, **but** it has zero content... and the only hint is the (odd to me) `mysqldump: Command not found.`

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing the same problem, the issue is with user access to 'root/bin' dir.

switch your user access as root

```
    sudo -s
```

Then execute the command

```
mysqldump -uroot -p homestayadvisorDB > homestayadvisor_backup.sql
```

This will resolve the issue. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the man page for mysqldump for correct argument usage. You need a space between the `-u` flag and the username, like so:

```
mysqldump -u root -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql
```

Alternatively you can do

```
mysqldump --user=root -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql
```

Since you're not providing a password in the list of arguments, you should be prompted for one. You can always provide the password in the list of arguments, but the downside to that is it appears in cleartext and will show up in the shell's command history.

Comment: Anson, Thanks, but I tried those too:

    mysqldump -u root -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql  

&

    mysqldump --user=root -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql  

...with the same result:  
"myTestDumpedTable.sql: Permission denied."

It never prompts me for a password on my local dev setup and I assumed (since last time I was educating myself on running a MySQL install) that is because I never set up a password for the root user.  For certain I never need a password when I log into MySQL with "-uroot". That is fine with me since it is just me on this dev machine.

Comment: @govinda Ok, it's possible that you're authenticating to mysql just fine. Upon second inspection, it seems like your "permission denied" error might refer to the fact that you don't have write permission in the current directory. Are you running the command as the root user (type `whoami` before running the command)? Try running as root and being in the root user's home directory when running the command.

Comment: OK, I tried this:  when I type `whoami`, I get my username `Govind`.  So then, to try your suggestion, I use `su` to be the root user, fine.. and then `mysqldump -uroot -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql` produces `sh: mysqldump: command not found`, which is odd because it does produce a zero-KB file named "myTestDumpedTable.sql" in that dir.  So then I try `cd /var/root` (Mac OS X), and again `mysqldump -uroot -p myDBname myTableName > myTestDumpedTable.sql` produces `sh: mysqldump: command not found`... again a zero-KB file named "myTestDumpedTable.sql", in /var/root.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'd created the directory with `$ sudo mkdir /directory/to/store/sql/files`. The owner of that directory is `root`. So changing the owner by using `$ sudo chown me:me /directory/to/store/sql/files` and also changing permissions to maybe `$ sudo chmod 744 /directory/to/store/sql/files` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump don't work with sudo, if you are using

sudo mysqldump then try below solution:

```
sudo su
mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] db_name > newbackupfile.bkp
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide with a full path for SQL backup file, such as

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasexxx > /Users/yourusername/Sites/yoursqlfile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `./` from the command, try:
being inside

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin$ ./mysqldump -u root -p myDBname > "/Users/yourUserName/Documents/myTestDumpedTable.sql"
```

So it is a script, and in linux you execute a script with `./myscript`. 
I found it just today, and for me, in my mac OSX, I didn't use the `-p`, maybe because password not needed, don't know already. I mean, try also:

```
./mysqldump -u root myDBname > "/Users/yourUserName/Documents/myTestDumpedTable.sql"
```